# Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-router, react-rails

I'm using the react-rails gem (v 2.3) with react-router-dom (v 4.2.2) and mounting my root component App on my root Rails route.

This is how it's being mounted:

```
<%= react_component("App") %>
```

And this is the component itself:

```
const Router     = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter,
  Route      = ReactRouterDOM.Route;

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

Am I not using the Route component within a Router component above?
Is there an error perhaps with the Index component?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not correct error ..
Try override your App like that

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Index} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Or wrapp you `Route` in `div`

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <div>
            <Route path="/" component={Index} />
         </div>
       </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error message, but in a different context. I'm posting my fix here just in case someone else encounters the same situation I did.

My issue was that I'd had an App.js with two  elements added, but I had forgotten to update my index.js file. It had previously been:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

which I updated to:

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

which also had to add the following import statement:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```